# Force page to refresh after a POST angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, post

I tried to put a $ state.reload in my controller after a POST request, but it does not refresh my page. Therefore, after I register my form, the data is not updated on my page .. I am obliged to refresh manually so that it shows me the right data.

```
.controller('editCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, AppService) { 
$scope.infos = AppService.getObject();
console.log($scope.infos);
AppService.user($scope.infos).then(function(response){   
    $scope.user = response; 
    console.log($scope.user);           
});
$scope.save = function (currObj) {        
    AppService.edituser($scope.form,$scope.infos).then(function(response){
        AppService.addObject(currObj);
        console.log(currObj);           
        $state.reload('menu.infosUser'); 
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $state.go('menu.infosUser',{reload: true});
    });
}; 
})
```

I will reply as soon as possible to all proposals :)

Comment: sounds like all you really need to do is update your data

Comment: Yes, but actually the data is already updated after the Post request, but the page only displays the old data because it kept them cached ..

Comment: Which is the `$scope` variable you are trying to update after POST request?

Comment: After the post, the items I want to update have changed well in the database. But it is just at the level of the display that it does not appear directly, I have to update myself the page so that it is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to reload your page then use `location.reload()` for reloading the page like

```
.controller('editCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, AppService) { 
$scope.infos = AppService.getObject();
console.log($scope.infos);
AppService.user($scope.infos).then(function(response){   
    $scope.user = response; 
    console.log($scope.user);           
});
$scope.save = function (currObj) {        
    AppService.edituser($scope.form,$scope.infos).then(function(response){
        AppService.addObject(currObj);
        console.log(currObj);           
        location.reload();
    });
}; 
})
```

Or you can reload your state by using only `$state.go('menu.infosUser',{reload: true});`, it will clear your cached data, Eg

```
.controller('editCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, AppService) { 
$scope.infos = AppService.getObject();
console.log($scope.infos);
AppService.user($scope.infos).then(function(response){   
    $scope.user = response; 
    console.log($scope.user);           
});
$scope.save = function (currObj) {        
    AppService.edituser($scope.form,$scope.infos).then(function(response){
        AppService.addObject(currObj);
        console.log(currObj);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $state.go('menu.infosUser',{reload: true});
    });
}; 
})
```

Comment: what is the problem you face using this